# If $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ is finite dim $\mathbb{C}$-vsp, does it have a monomial basis? Related to Hilbert Scheme of points in the plane.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Background (You can skip ahead if you wish): I'm trying to read [this](http://www.math.duke.edu/~ezra/MSRIworkshop/msriWorkshop.pdf) article about the Hilbert Scheme of points in the plane, and I don't understand one of the claims.

---

An ideal $I\subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is said to be of colength $n$ if the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space is $n.$

When I take a finite colength $I$ generated by monomials, it's pretty easy to find a monomial basis for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I.$ For example, $I= (x^2,xy,y^3)$ is of colength $4,$ and (the $I$ residues of) $1, x, y, y^2$ form a $\mathbb{C}$-basis of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I.$

However, not every colength $n$ ideal is generated by monomials. The article claims (in the middle of the second page) "**Even though $I$ may not be expressible as a monomial ideal, the quotient $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ always has a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space basis of (images of) monomials**".

I have been unsuccessful in proving this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @user26857 I am only familiar with the finite version of the theorem you seem to be using - that is, I know that if I have a finite spanning set, there is some subset which is a basis. Do you have a reference for the more general fact (that any spanning set contains some subset which is a basis) ?

Comment: @user26857 Don't worry about the reference actually. I was thinking about the natural related questions (Does every vector space have a basis? etc), remembered Zorn's lemma is relevant and found a proof. :) . Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Every** quotient of a polynomial ring has a basis of (classes of) monomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ can be generated by $\{x^iy^j \mid i,j \geq 0 \}$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-module. Look at the natural *surjective* $\mathbb{C}$-module projection $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I,$ where $x^iy^j \mapsto \overline{x^iy^j}.$ The target will be generated by $\{\overline{x^iy^j} \mid i,j \geq 0\}$ and because it is finite dimensional only finitely many of them would suffice.